# Dynamically create and add a movieclip to the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, movieclip

Why won't this work?!

```
stop();
var board:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
board.width = 60 * 5;
board.height = 60 * 5;
board.graphics.clear();
board.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
board.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
board.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, board.width, board.height);
board.graphics.endFill();
this.addChild(board);
board.x = 40;
board.y = 40;
```

it's simple and has been done before countless times and yet it won't work for me!!!
I've pasted it into an actions frame and in a document script and neither works!!
It's frustrating me because I know this is right!!!
I'm using Flash CS5.5!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly -- it's been a while -- there is no `width` or `height` until there is something in the `MovieClip`.  Even if you set the dimensions manually, there is nothing to size, so they end up remaining at 0s.  You have to add an object or else draw something to `graphics` first, then you will be able to resize it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
board.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, board.width, board.height);
```

To:

```
board.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 60 * 5, 60 * 5);
```

Why:

I could be wrong, I haven't tested it but `board.width` and `board.height` are probably returning 0.

Comment: oh my god!! o.O
I updated the code snippet to this;

    'var board:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var bW:Number = 60 * 5;
    var bH:Number = 60 * 5;
    board.graphics.clear();
    board.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    board.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
    board.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, bW, bH);
    board.graphics.endFill();
    this.addChild(board);
    board.x = 40;
    board.y = 40;'

and it worked! WHY?! is it something to do with a movieclip not having dimensions before being added to stage?

Comment: @BlakcRece I don't even know why I bother answering question anymore(disregard that, just venting).